# PDF/A validation with embedded CID font subset caused by ligatures in vector image

Tags: pdftex, ligatures, inkscape, pdf-a

### Objective and Workflow

I want to produce a PDF/A-2b compliant PDF document with pdfLaTeX using the Package *pdfx*. The target document includes PDF vector images, which are exported from SVG sources with **Inkscape 0.91** using *Save As* and leaving *Convert texts to paths* unchecked. Those vector images contain text with **ligatures**, such as the one resulting from the character combination "ff". Of course, a font supporting ligatures, **Linux Biolinum** TrueType in my case, is used. For PDF/A validation, I use the [3-Heights™ PDF Validator Online Tool](https://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx). See also the [example set of files](http://en.file-upload.net/download-12237660/pdfa-cidfonts.zip.html).

### Problem

Both the exported PDF vector image and the target PDF document created with pdfLaTeX, which includes the vector image, cause the following validation problem:

```
The key CIDToGIDMap is required but missing.
```

Without using ligatures in the text, the PDF file contains only the embedded subset:

- *LinBiolinum* with *Type: TrueType* and *Encoding: Ansi*

When using ligatures, the PDF file contains an additional embedded subset:

- *LinBiolinum* with *Type: TrueType (CID)* and *Encoding: Identity-H*

The validation problem occures if and only if the second subset is added, i. e., the use of ligatures causes a second font subset to be included in the PDF, which then causes the PDF/A validation issue. Another tool, veraPDF, associates it to [Rule 6.2.11.3-2](https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-validation-profiles/wiki/PDFA-Parts-2-and-3-rules#rule-62113-2).

### Question

How can the described workflow be adapted to use SVG images including text with ligatures while preserving PDF/A compatibility?

Comment: In Linux Biolinum, the ff ligature is named f_f rather than ff. This is perfectly OK, and is quite common among Open Type fonts. However, the file glyphtounicode.tex only has an entry for ff, not f_f. Could this be the cause of the problem? If it is, then the list could be enhanced by adding a number of common ligature names of this kind.

Comment: Interesting hint. How exactly is glyphtounicode.tex involved in the described process? Other ligatures such as `Qu` are affected as well.

Comment: Technically, I do not know. I just see and do. The glyphtounicode file is a list of glyph names and their Unicode values. The glyph named ff is a standard, and is supposed to occupy a particular Unicode point. It is listed in the file. But f_f is not standard and has no Unicode point of its own, although it might be placed at ff. It is not listed in the file. Same for Q_u, f_f_l, T_h, and others. No real limit. What glyphtounicode does is show which multiple Unicode characters are the decomposed ligature. Open the file and look, especially at ff. I believe you can add your own. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

So far I know of no TeX-based software that creates or otherwise handles `CIDToGIDMap` streams. They are needed particularly with CJK fonts, as used in documents produced with XeLaTeX. This is one of the last few hurdles that prevent generating PDF/A-conforming CJK documents with XeLaTeX.

Proper support is something that I want to incorporate into `pdfx.sty`, so I'm looking for examples to aid in development. Could you possibly send me a small-ish example document which shows the problem in a non-CJK setting?  (ross.moore@mq.edu.au)

Comment: I added an example set of files to the question.